# Input clock limit

Tags: oscillator-clock, input

If you use an external oscillator, and divide-by-8 internally, can you apply up to 160MHz on PB6? For example, can I use my 50MHz oscillator to clock my 328p @ 6250KHz? Note: when I say oscillator I don't mean resonator or crystal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No! 20 MHz max (Please see [8.8 External Clock, pp. 34](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc8161.pdf)). The 50MHz clock could be divided by 8 with a [counter](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT393.pdf) or the 150MHz clock by 16 with a [faster counter](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/74/74VHC393.pdf).

Cheers!

Comment: So divide-by-8 doesn't apply to external oscillators?

Comment: Exactly. The external clock is max 20 MHz and then it may be divided internally.